# Calculate $\dim W+V$ and $W\cap V$

Tags: linear-algebra

This is a task from an old exam.

Let define:

$V_{t} = \text{lin}((1,2,2,1),(1,1,-1,t))$

$W = \cases{x_1-x_2=0\\x_3-x_4 =0}$

Calculate $\dim W+V_{t}$ and $\dim W\cap V_{t}$

Please verify answer below

Comment: Which do you want to know: $W \cap V$ or $W \cup V$? Your questions title and the question itself disagree.

Comment: @FlybyNight Judging by his answer he wants $W \cap V$.

Comment: The first one is correct, fixed. Thanks

Comment: Why post a question and then an answer one minute later?! The reply obviously took longer than one minute to type. The intention was clearly to post a question and an answer... I don't get it.

Comment: @FlybyNight Yes, Git Gud is right

Comment: @GitGud "**Don't Cry**" http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/282898/integral-help-here-please#comment617415_282898

Comment: @GitGud Yes... I *have*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

basis of $W$ = $\text{lin} ((1,1,0,0),(0,0,1,1))$

$ W+V_{t}=\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
1 & 2 & 2 & 1\\
1 & 1 & -1 & t\\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1
\end{array}\right]\sim\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
1 & 2 & 2 & 1\\
0 & -1 & -3 & t-1\\
0 & -1 & -2 & -1\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1
\end{array}\right]\sim\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
1 & 2 & 2 & 1\\
0 & 0 & -1 & t\\
0 & -1 & -2 & -1\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1
\end{array}\right]\sim\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
1 & 2 & 2 & 1\\
0 & -1 & -2 & -1\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & t+1
\end{array}\right]
 $

$\dim W+V_{t}=3$ for $t=-1$ and $4$ in other case.

$V_{t}:$

$\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 1 & x_{1}\\
2 & 1 & x_{2}\\
2 & -1 & x_{3}\\
1 & t & x_{4}
\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 1 & x_{1}\\
0 & 0 & x_{2}-2x_{1}\\
0 & -2 & x_{3}-2x_{1}\\
0 & t & x_{4}-2x_{1}
\end{array}\right]\implies V_{1}:\begin{cases}
x_{2}-2x_{1}=0\\
x_{4}-2x_{1}=0
\end{cases}
 $

$W\cap V_{t}:\begin{cases}
x_{1}-x_{2}=0\\
x_{3}-x_{4}=0\\
x_{2}-2x_{1}=0\\
x_{4}-2x_{1}=0
\end{cases}
 $

$\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
1 & -1 & 0 & 0\\
 &  & 1 & -1\\
-2 & 1\\
-2 &  &  & 1
\end{array}\right]\sim\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
1 & -1 & 0 & 0\\
 &  & 1 & -1\\
0 & -1\\
0 & -2 &  & 1
\end{array}\right]\sim\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
1 & -1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & -1\\
 &  & 1 & -1\\
0 & -2 &  & 1
\end{array}\right]\sim\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
1 & -1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & -1\\
 &  & 1 & -1\\
0 & 0 &  & 1
\end{array}\right]
 $

$\dim W\cap V_{t}=0
 $

Comment: You seem to apply an equivalence relation on the space of matrices. What does it mean to say that $M \sim N$? Is it actually an equivalence relation?

Comment: I'm following an algorithm to create row reduced (echelon) form of matrix in this steps

Comment: @FlybyNight Using $\sim$ in this context means the following matrix is row or column equivalent to the previous one, which is a way to tidily write down the solution to a system of equations. I didn't read it over but it doesn't look wrong.

Comment: @Steve "$\dim W+V_{t}=3$ for $t=1$". Did you mean $t=-1$?

Comment: @GitGud Yes. Fixed. Thanks

Comment: @Steve I don't really follow what you're doing on $W \cap V_t$. Are you doing it for all $t$ or just $t=1$?

Comment: @GitGud I've got, that it doesn't matter what is t, becasue we can remove t during the operations. There is the matter of my problem, because it seems to be incorrect. But I don't know why, I was doing everything like in other examples

Comment: @Steve Can you please tell me how did you get $\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 1 & x_{1}\\
2 & 1 & x_{2}\\
2 & -1 & x_{3}\\
1 & t & x_{4}
\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 1 & x_{1}\\
0 & 0 & x_{2}-2x_{1}\\
0 & -2 & x_{3}-2x_{1}\\
0 & t & x_{4}-2x_{1}
\end{array}\right]$?


Also note that you shouldn't use the $=$ sign.

Comment: @GitGud I've made elementary steps to reduce this matrix.

Comment: @Steve It seems to me, looking at the entries on the third row, that you replaced the third row with $\displaystyle R_3-2R_1$, but $\textbf{if}$ that's what you did, then the second entry of third row is wrong. I gotta go now. Good luck with that.