# $\lim_{R \to \infty} \int_0^R \frac{dx}{(x^2+x+2)^3}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

> $$\lim_{R \to \infty} \int_0^R \frac{dx}{(x^2+x+2)^3}$$

Please help me in this integral, I've tried some substitutions, but nothing work.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: @amWhy listing 10 substitutions and rewritting them in latex won't help, if they are wrong.

Comment: I am among the most tolerant of users here, but I generally expect more from someone who's acquired more than 1K of reputation, and hence, "knows the ropes" of posting a good question.

Comment: @amWhy I've seen a lot of Steve's questions. He's a *good* user. If  it means anything, trust me.

Comment: please let me do another tasks in this time, and allow other user to give a clues for this task

Comment: @GitGud Thanks! :-)

Comment: @GitGud Nice to know. Can you explain how said *good user* can ask 5 questions in such a short time span, each flouting the rules of the site, and refuse to add anything personal to them?

Comment: @Did what do You expect from me? bunch of papers rewritted into latex to make a prof, that I don't waste time this evening?

Comment: @Did I really can't, but my previous experience with him was nothing like this. He showed a lot of effort. [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/283758/calculate-dim-wv-and-w-cap-v) particular question comes to mind.

Comment: lets stay to the topic here... @Steve, a lot of these integrals are solved by subsituting with $\tan(...)$. Check out, what WolframAlpha does: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate[1%2F%28x^2%2Bx%2B2%29^3%2Cx]

Comment: @GitGud I agree with you about the other question. What about the present one? (Not to mention the disquieting last comments by the OP.)

Comment: @Did My comment was misleading, I only ment to attest to my past experience with him.

Comment: @GitGud No prob.

Comment: @Did It's good to clarify this. $\ddot \smile$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First complete the square:
$$
x^2 + x + 2 = \left( x^2 + x + \tfrac{1}{4} \right) + \tfrac{7}{4} = \left( x + \tfrac{1}{2} \right)^2 + \left( \tfrac{\sqrt{7}}{2} \right)^2.
$$
Now, make the (inverse) trigonometric substitution:
$$
\tan t = \frac{x + \tfrac{1}{2}}{\tfrac{\sqrt{7}}{2}}.
$$
This choice of ratio is motivated by the sum of square expression above.  As a consequence, we have
$$
x^2 + x + 2 = \left( \tfrac{\sqrt{7}}{2} \tan t \right)^2 + \left( \tfrac{\sqrt{7}}{2} \right)^2 = \tfrac{7}{4} \left( \tan^2 t + 1 \right) = \tfrac{7}{4} \sec^2 t.
$$
Now, the differential is
$$
dx = \tfrac{\sqrt{7}}{2} \sec^2 t \, dt
$$
and the limits of integration become
$$
\begin{align}
x &= 0 &\Longleftrightarrow \quad t(0) &= \arctan \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{7}} \\
x &= R &\Longleftrightarrow \quad t(R) &= \arctan \tfrac{2R + 1}{\sqrt{7}}.
\end{align}
$$
Now, substitute:
$$
\int_0^R \frac{dx}{(x^2 + x + 2)^3} = \int_{t(0)}^{t(R)} \frac{\tfrac{\sqrt{7}}{2} \sec^2 t \, dt}{\left( \tfrac{7}{4} \sec^2 t \right)^3} = \left( \tfrac{2}{\sqrt{7}} \right)^5 \int_{t(0)}^{t(R)} \cos^4 t \, dt.
$$
Can you finish it from here, using [power reducing identities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Power-reduction_formula)?